# How can I tell if a kernel has some "new" config?

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm making a simple kernel auto build script, right now I need to detect if there's a new config that need to ask the user (I don't want to use the default value), if so, it launches `make menuconfig` first, otherwise skip that part.

Normally it just ask me to pick between `N`, `Y`, `M`.

Is it possible?

Comment: `make oldconfig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of `make listnewconfig`.